# How do I ensure my piranha solution chemical weapon will only eat the target and not me?

Tags: weapons, chemistry, weapon-mass-destruction

I want to use piranha solution to kill a large, horrible thing that I really don't like.

[Piranha solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution) is an acid [that makes organic substances not exist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTVd_WxblGI) and [can dissolve elemental carbon](https://sciencenotes.org/piranha-solution-preparation-use-and-safety/). You concoct it by:

- mixing 3 to 7 parts of concentrated [sulfuric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfuric_acid) and 1 part of 30%-by-weight [hydrogen peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_peroxide) solution
- quickly running away, because, to paraphrase [a certain god of blood and war](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Khorne), piranha solution cares not from who the flesh melts off of, only that it does

Additionally, it is highly unsafe to mix quickly. To quote piranha solution's Wikipedia page:

> Piranha solution should always be prepared by adding hydrogen peroxide
> to sulfuric acid slowly, never in reverse order. This minimises **[sic]**
> the concentration of hydrogen peroxide during the mixing process,
> helping to reduce instantaneous heat generation and explosion risk. Mixing the solution is an extremely exothermic process. If the solution is made rapidly, it will instantly boil, releasing large amounts of corrosive fumes.  Even when made with care, the resulting heat can easily bring the solution temperature above 100 °C. It must be allowed to cool reasonably before it is used. A sudden increase in temperature can also lead to a violent boiling of the extremely acidic solution.

As such, I want it to mix only at the instant it arrives on-target - preferably ***F̴͝ͅÃ̵͍R̶̻̓*** away from me. Essentially, I will keep the sulfuric acid and the hydrogen peroxide separate for as long as possible.

**The question: how do I:**

**- (A) ensure that the sulfuric acid and hydrogen peroxide *only* mix once they arrive at the target**

**- (B) minimize the risk of the sulfuric acid and hydrogen peroxide mixing *before* they arrive at the target**

Bonus points for coming up with a method that lets them mix quickly, so that the target gets to deal with a violent [exothermic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exothermic_process) reaction/explosion as well as the nightmarishly corrosive fumes.

Extra bonus points for making its delivery method some kind of human-portable weapon, such as a grenade or a sprayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Copy the soda acid type fire extinguisher**

As explained [here](https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/explain-the-working-of-soda-acid-type-fire-extinguisher-5b865e3be4b034918acd5bb1),

> this type of fire extinguisher contains a bottle of sulfuric acid
> supported by a metallic container filled with a baking soda solution.
> When the cylinder is inverted and knob struck, against the ground, the
> acid bottle breaks and the acid comes into contact with the backing
> soda.

In similar way, you can fill the container with hydrogen peroxide and put the glass bottle containing sulfuric acid. Break the bottle when you are away and they are close.

This can be done in different ways.

- Throw this bomb from a distance (manually or with a cannon or
  slingshot) so that when it falls on them, the glass bottle breaks and
  mixture falls on them.
- Use the bomb like a land mine. They will hit it when they arrive close.
- Use a timer device to break the bottle, so that you have enough time to run away.
- Use a remote control to break the bottle.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could put hydrogen peroxide into "menthos" and push the pellets into your bottle of sulphuric acid "coke". Then the product is extruded rigorously out of the bottleneck and into your target.

Teenagers doing that experiment seem to be able to do the mixing and run away really quickly.

Just add something to the peroxide which will produce a lot of gas when in contact with the acid and will momentarily decompose and disperse the peroxide.

Comment: That's true mad scientist thinking! +1

Answer (score 3):

Since Piranha Solution can be used to clean glassware (although it is discouraged), I don't see what's stopping you from placing the Sulfuric acid and Hydrogen Peroxide in 2 small compartment within a glass container which could be thrown at your enemies. Yout might have issues with sealing the container however using glass means it would likely break upon hitting something from a distance, especially launching it with speed and power. Smashing glass on someone is already a weapon so combining it with piranha solution? Even more deadly. Just be careful you don't drop them I suppose :)

Answer (score 2):

Does this large horrible thing have a home or lair you can visit while the large horrible thing is away?

A big beaker of hydrogen peroxide set up to fall into a bigger bucket of acid would be a fairly simple trap to set. This puts a lot more of the ingredients together than a portable version. Unless your large horrible thing is a seriously huge dragon, it won't be around to engage in any more large horible activities after this.

Answer (score 2):

### Ghostbusters

One of you has a backpack of concentrated sulfuric acid strapped to his back; the less lucky one has a backpack of 30% peroxide.   You have "protective gear" that hopefully includes such things as a scuba mask, a layer of tinfoil to keep the rubber on the mask from turning into an explosive from sprayed peroxide too quickly, tinfoil hat, tinfoil athletic supporter, and an unusual amount of luck.  *Take great care not to cross the streams* except as circumstances require.